# Object Oriented Design approach to a conversion app

Tags: oop

I think i might be being blinded by the way I've learned OO principles. Its always taught in the manner of tangible object is a descendant of another tangible object. Anyway...

I'm trying to work out an OO approach to a conversion utility, basically it will read a text file and based on the first word(s) on the line it will go off and translate / do whatever corresponds. Would this be a case of each command is a new object or...

Its probably a simple answer but I'm struggling

Comment: Josh, can you be a bit more specific about your requirements? What's being converted to what? What is the role and format of the text file you mention? Is there some essential subset of those requirements that is absolutely necessary for the first version, as opposed to things you might want to have in an ideal/future version?

Comment: Its kyocera printer commands, converting them to XSL-FO. As an example a line might be:

MZP 4,3;

All this is doing is moving the position of the following draw/text commands to 4 inches in, 3 inches down. I wouldnt be supporting all commands to begin with but all i intend for future versions is increased command support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern), and the [Factory Method](http://www.dofactory.com/patterns/patternfactory.aspx) patterns.

Answer (score 2):

I did this once for a database conversion application. I had **import** plugins (classes) that read data into a common model. Then the **export** plugins (classes) read the common model and wrote it out to a database. In my case, this was a .NET application, so I used MEF to split the importers and exporters into different assemblies. Customers could plug in whatever importers and exporters they needed, or could even write their own if they wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I would not get too caught up in OO design for something like this.  OO principles should be used only if they are obvious and help you with reuse.  That might not be the case here.  Also, this does not sound like a large app.  The pitfall people fall into is making way too many classes just to get a little bit of reuse.  This quickly makes things unmanageable.  Just do it the old-fashioned way and if something jumps out at you where inheritance can help for example, then use it.

Comment: Thats absoultely untrue. Designing this in an OO approach allows for the application to be extended later on with new keywords/tokens and it allows for complete separation of functionality from interface.

Comment: OOP is not only about reuse, it's also about separating what varies so that parts can very independently of each other. This is a great example of parts that vary independently of each other: the format of the input and the format of the output. So your claim that OOP makes "things" unmanageable strikes me as being a bit naive. Having all of the code responsibilities lumped in a huge transaction script will definitely be unmanageable.

Comment: Perhaps you could take a closer look at what I have written, I don't think what I'm saying contradicts what you say.  It's just that people tend to put in too much extensibility sometimes and it makes things overly complicated.

Comment: @RibaldWEddie, I did not make the claim that you suggest.  I was responding the OPs comment about perhaps having a class for each command.

Comment: @Francis ... I did read what you wrote.. small applications (espically with this type of feature) become large quite quickly.

Comment: @steven, they may or may not get large, and as they do, and that can be the point to consider adding more classes and hierarchy, and to refactor as necessary.  I guess I'm with the "simplest thing that can possibly work" school (as long as it's minimum code and no duplication).